# Query with GROUP_CONCAT not working with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display certain values through GROUP_CONCAT, and GROUP BY, yet only the groups are showing when I test it out, and the other values don't.

```
function events_calendar() {
     global $connection;
     mysqli_select_db($connection);
     $query = ("SELECT month, GROUP_CONCAT(start_date) as data FROM events GROUP BY month");
     $result = $connection->query($query);
     $str = "";
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row['month'];
         echo $row['start_date'];
     }
     return $str;
}
```

The month values show up, but the start_date values don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the PHP.  Try replacing:

```
     echo $row['start_date'];
```

with:

```
     echo $row['data'];
```

You need to use the column alias that you assigned in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I change the alias when answering his other question.